# MS UI Automation not working on 3rd party ERP app

Tags: user-interface, automation, erp

I'm trying to integrate an MVC 2 project with a 3rd-party Win32 .exe ERP system.  I'm trying to field scrape from the MVC App and push the data to the ERP client.  The MVC front-end is much more stable and user-friendly than the ERP client.  I don't know what language the ERP client was written in, only that it is a client-server app that runs on a Unix box, and uses an all but obselete back-end database (Pick).

I've used MS UI Automation to load the process of the ERP client, but the only elements it is finding are the standard window elements (Title Bar, Context Menu, Minimize, Maximize, Close).  The client ERP is loaded with text boxes, buttons, pick lists...but UI Automation doesn't recognize any of them.

Can anyone give some insight into why the controls aren't recognized, and how I might work around that?

(And this would be even more helpful) Can anyone recommend an open-source, mid-sized ERP system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that the UI controls do not have window handles.  Visual Foxpro applications had the same issue.  They were custom controls that did not use the underlying OS controls with Window handles.

As far as Open Source ERP, take a look at http://www.xtuple.com/

Comment: It must be as you've said, they don't use Windows handles underneath their controls.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting xtuple, that came up in our search too.